# Why is u-channel diagram kinked in such way?

Tags: feynman-diagrams

Let us consider Bhabha scattering as an example. Using Mandelstam variables, we can think about u-channel Feynman diagrams (see below). Notice the kink at the first two vertices where virtual particle photon is being exchanged. I suspect that the kinks are due to momentum transfer (i.e. momentum conservation), however, I don't understand them why. It seems like they should be kinked the other way around like the kink Bremsstrahlung radiation (see second picture).

It would be appreciated if someone could shed some light on this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The shape has nothing to do with momentum. It’s just that if you don’t draw a kink, you can’t tell it apart from a t-channel diagram.

Comment: @knzhou Why can't you tell it apart from a t-channel? You can identify it by where the virtual particle propagates.

Comment: None of the electrons in the u-channel diagram you drew are virtual.

Comment: But in t-channel are they virtual?

Comment: No. Only the photon is virtual.

Comment: I meant the photon in the t-channel.

Comment: In both the t-channel and the u-channel the photon is in general virtual.

Comment: I see. Can you explain why the electrons in the u-channel are virtual, and in t-channel real?

Comment: I can't explain that because it is not true. None of the electrons are virtual.

Comment: I said wrong things. Let me rephrase what I'm going to say.
Can you elaborate why none of the electrons in the u-channel are virtual compared to t-channel?